# nodejs: save data of sortable menu with javascript and send it to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, jquery-ui-sortable, mongoose-schema

**SOLVED!!**

I have a popup window with a sortable menu made with javascript. The elements of the menu belong to a mongoose schema and I want to update the database according to the new order list coming from the menu. let me explain better. I have this mongoose schema:

```
({
  title: { type: String },
  POI: [{
   POIname: { type: String },
   POIlocation: { type: String },
   POItext: { type: String }
  }]
})
```

I pass the array POIs from Express to the client side,

```
    #popupbox
      #riordinabox
        #divhead
          span#exitbox(onclick="closepopupbox('popupbox')", title="EXIT") X
          p Trascina il POI per riordinare la lista
        #divlistaPOI
          each POI in POIs
            .divpopupbox(id="#{POI.POIname}", draggable="true", ondragenter="dragenter(event)" ondragstart="dragstart(event)")
              p #{POI.POIname}
        #divfooter
```

and, as you can see, the .POIname elements create the menu. The user is allowed to change the order of the list and save the new order. For example the default order is:

```
({
  title: "sometitle",
  POI: [{
   POIname: "jump",
   POIlocation: table,
   POItext: "jump on the table"
  }],
     [{
   POIname: "run",
   POIlocation: street,
   POItext: "run on the street"
  }],
     [{
   POIname: "turnR",
   POIlocation: everywhere,
   POItext: "turn right"
  }]
})
```

and the sortable menu shows:

- jump
- run
- turnR

After the user action, the new order list is:

- run
- turnR
- jump

Now I want to get the new order and set the same order in the database,  therefore I can see

```
({
  title: "sometitle",
  POI: [{
   POIname: "run",
   POIlocation: street,
   POItext: "run on the street"
  }],
     [{
   POIname: "turnR",
   POIlocation: everywhere,
   POItext: "turn right"
  }],
     [{
   POIname: "jump",
   POIlocation: table,
   POItext: "jump on the table"
  }]
})
```

and I know which step comes first.

Any ideas?

thank you!

Comment: why don't you use array? `var steps = [{step1}, {step2}, {step3}]`, that way you can just update the step like this, `var temp = step[1]; steps[0] = temp, steps[1] = step[0]`

Comment: Yes, but the very big problem is how to send and set the new order to Mongodb!

Comment: you actually can save it as it is, the whole steps array, `document.title = "sometitle"; document.steps = steps; document.save()` it depends how you built your schema

Answer (score 0):

@YanMayatskiy we are close to the end. I did this code:

```
 router.get('/:name/orderlist/:list', function(req, res, next) {
  Itinerario.findOne({name: req.params.name}, function(err, itinerario){
    if (err) throw err;
    var temp = [];
    var array = JSON.parse(req.params.list);
    res.send(array);
    for (i=0; i<array.length; i++){
      if (itinerario.POI[i].POIname === array[i]){
        temp[i] = itinerario.POI[i];
      } else {
        var j = 0;
        while (true){
          if( itinerario.POI[i].POIname === array[j] ){
            break;
          }
          j++
        }
        temp[j] = itinerario.POI[i];
      }
    }
    for (i=0; i<temp.length; i++){
      itinerario.POI[i] = temp[i];
    }
    itinerario.save(function (err, itinerario){
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(itinerario);
    })
  })
});
```

it works correctly, but there is an issue! At the end, when I log the "itinerario" model I can see in the prompt the new order of the steps:

```
({
  title: "sometitle",
  POI: [{
   POIname: "run",
   POIlocation: street,
   POItext: "run on the street"
  }],
     [{
   POIname: "turnR",
   POIlocation: everywhere,
   POItext: "turn right"
  }],
     [{
   POIname: "jump",
   POIlocation: table,
   POItext: "jump on the table"
  }]
})
```

but, if I do the find() method in the mongo prompt I still see the old order of the steps!!!!!!

```
({
  title: "sometitle",
  POI: [{
   POIname: "jump",
   POIlocation: table,
   POItext: "jump on the table"
  }],
     [{
   POIname: "run",
   POIlocation: street,
   POItext: "run on the street"
  }],
     [{
   POIname: "turnR",
   POIlocation: everywhere,
   POItext: "turn right"
  }]
})
```

Infact when I refresh the page, I get the old order again. It doesn't save the new order in the database!!!!

I'm going crazy!

Comment: solved! Just add itinerario.markModified('POI'); before save(). Yeah!